# How to separate a string as according to a condition, using split?

Tags: javascript

good morning I have these text strings:

```
json_schema.account_overview.name
json_schema.no_owned.contact.contact
```

but now I'm trying to separate according to the string 'json_schema.no_owned', doing like this:

```
my_string.split ("json_schema.no_owned."). filter (x => x);
```

but doing a console.log of that result I get this

[image]

the first arrangement is fine, since to that same arrangement I can apply another split and I will have again separated by '.'
but the second fix has nothing to do with what I was saying should be after 'json_schema.no_owned.' (note the period at the end)

This way I am trying to do it:

```js
let string ="json_schema.no_owned.contact.contact";
let arrayString = [
  'json_schema.no_owned.contact.contact',
  'json_schema.account_overview.name'
];

let schema = "";
for(let i in arrayString){
   schema = arrayString[i].split("json_schema.no_owned.").filter(x => x);
console.log(schema);   
}
```

I only want to have in an array the elements that are after 'json_schema.no_owned'
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if element has "json_schema.no_owned." part at all:

```js
let string ="json_schema.no_owned.contact.contact";
let arrayString = [
  'json_schema.no_owned.contact.contact',
  'json_schema.account_overview.name'
];

let schema = "";
for(let i in arrayString){
   if (arrayString[i].includes("json_schema.no_owned.")) {
      schema = arrayString[i].split("json_schema.no_owned.").filter(x => x);
      console.log(schema);  
   }
}
```

Comment: @JG_GJ You could accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a short way to do it.

```
let arrayString = [
  'json_schema.no_owned.contact.contact',
  'json_schema.account_overview.name'
];

const schemas = arrayString.filter(x => x.includes("json_schema.no_owned."))
                           .map(x => x.split("json_schema.no_owned.")[1]);
```